# Why can't I rename SharepointForm1 to something else?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, powerapps

I have a custom form tied to list "Furniture Order Form" that looks like this

[image]

When I change the name of the form to "FormView", the controls on the form disappear.

[image]
Why is this happening and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: can you try this: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-PowerApps/How-to-bring-a-text-box-forward/m-p/75251/highlight/true#M315

Answer (score 0):

This caused by position&size changing.

My Test Result.

[image]

Comment: I watched  DeShon Clark's video "PA: 2 of 5 | Customizing New, Edit, View Forms SP List - PowerApps Tutorial for Beginners" on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gaCTT7bPuQg where he duplicated  the main screen twice and renamed screens and forms without any problems.    When i then tried to do the same thing, I ran into that problem.  How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

After you rename the form, you have to set every datacard's Width to: **Parent.Width**

See: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/Data-card-fields-disappear-after-renaming-form/m-p/352684#M101100